# I want to know the meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from 'The picture of Dorian Gray'.

He  would often spend a whole day settling and resettling in their cases the various stones that **be had collected**, such as the olive...........(I have omitted such long following).

Isn't 'be had collected' correct?

Comment: It looks like a typo. Corrected, it would be 'he had collected'.

Comment: Google has a whopping 37,500 results for "He would often spend a whole day settling and resettling in their cases the various stones that **be** had collected" and only 5,110 for the same quote with "he" instead of "be". Perhaps a longstanding error?

Comment: Either a typo or an OCR error. *h* in some fonts looks like a *b*. Most of the hits for "that be had collected" in google books are actually for "that he had collected".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo or OCR error.

Answer (score 2):

No, it certainly is 'he had collected'.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the sentence is that your book had an editor who missed an error.

It seems likely to be:  *he* had collected.

And the likelihood only goes up when you consider the proximity of the <kbd>b</kbd> key to the <kbd>h</kbd>  key on a traditional QWERTY keyboard.